# Showing a function extends another with the Helly, Hahn-Banach analytic theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The following is a corollary in my book which I want to prove.

> Let $\mathbb{E}$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and let $G
> > \subset \mathbb{E}$. If $g: G \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous linear
>   functional, then there exists $f \in \mathbb{E^{\star}}$ that extends
>   $g$ and such that $$||f||_{\mathbb{E}^{\star}} = \sup_{x\in G, \; x\in
> > \mathbb{E}} |g(x)| = ||g||_{G^{\star}}$$

There is a hint to use the Helly, Hahn-Banach analytic theorem with the function $p(x) = ||g||_{G^{\star}} ||x||$

Since $p(x)$ is a function made up by norms, then it satisfies $$p(\lambda x) = ||g||_{G^{\star}}||\lambda x|| = ||g||_{G^{\star}}\lambda ||x||, \forall x \in \mathbb{E} \text{ and } \lambda > 0,$$

$$p(x+y) = ||g||_{G^{\star}}||x+y|| \leq ||g||_{G^{\star}} \left (||x|| + ||y|| \right ) .$$

These are the first two conditions of the H.B.T analytic form satisfied. There is a third condition saying

> Let $G \subset E$ be a linear subspace and let $g: G \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear functional such that $$g(x) \leq p(x), \; \forall x \in E$$

How do we know that for any function $g$ from the corollary, that condition will be satisfied?

Answer (score 1):

Your notation and definition and question is unclear. The Hahn-Banach theorem has many formulations, the one we care is

> $X,\|.\|$ is a real Banach space and $Y \subset X$ a vector space. If a linear form $h : Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded on $Y$ (ie. $\|h\|_{Y^*} = \sup_{y \in Y, \|y\| = 1} |h(y)| < \infty$) then it can be extended to a bounded linear form $\tilde{h} : X \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\|\tilde{h}\|_{X^*} = \|h\|_{Y^*}$.

For the proof we need the more general

> Now $X$ is a real vector space. If a linear form $h : Y \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $|h(y)| \le p(y)$ where $p : X \to \mathbb{R}^+, p(x+y)\le  p(x)+ p(y),p(ax)\le |a|p(x) $ (a sub-additive function) then $h$ can be extended to $\tilde{h} : X \to \mathbb{R}$ with $|\tilde{h}(x)| \le p(x)$.

If $h$ was bounded for $\|.\|$ then we can take $p(x) = \|h\|_{Y^*} \|x\|$ and obtain the preceding version.